# Why this sentence need to add "within" after "from"?

Tags: prepositions

In this sentence

> Sampling is concerned with the selection of a subset of individuals from within a statistical population to estimate characteristics of the whole population."

It seems to me that "within" could be removed without changing the meaning.

Am I wrong? What's the difference with and without "within"?

Comment: No difference except redundancy. _From_ with an object representing a volume means 'from within that volume'. However, redundancy is what allows language to function even though not everyone understands perfectly; it's a feature, not a bug. Just like _do_-support and inversion is redundant in questions, but still a good idea.

Comment: The "from" preposition has many different senses. This just makes it clearer how it's being used.